# node-bigcommerce Get and Post Routes

Tags: npm, routes, bigcommerce

I'm using the npm package, 'node bigcommerce', and I have all my API's setup but whenever I try to make a GET route, the error, `Error: Request returned error code: 404 and body: The route is not found, check the URL`, shows up. I don't know how or where to specify the url to find. Also, I have the same problem with POST Routes. The code is here. Thanks ahead!

```
var express     = require('express'),
    BigCommerce = require('node-bigcommerce');

var bigCommerce = new BigCommerce({
    clientId: '* Client ID *',
    secret: '* Secret *',
    callback: 'https://store-xxi13.mybigcommerce.com',
    responceType: 'json',
    accessToken: '* Access Token *',
    storeHash: 'xxi13'
});

bigCommerce.get('/happy', (data) =>{
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path supplied in your get request, `'/happy'` is not a BigCommerce API endpoint--that's why you're getting a 404 not found. If you made a request to `/products` for example, it should work to pull product data.

Also, the callback would usually be a path on your app, not the store URL. For example, `callback: 'https://myapplication.com/auth',` would be the path on your app where you want the BigCommerce auth service to send your temporary code and Oauth token during the installation flow:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/#app-installation-and-update-sequence

You can find examples of configuring the client and making requests in the README for the node-bigcommerce client:
https://github.com/getconversio/node-bigcommerce

Comment: I put '/products' in the GET command but I still get the error. I'm using some of the code from the documentation too but that code won't work either

Comment: Have you set the API version? If not try using `/v3/products` instead? We have a v2 and v3 products endpoint and they need to be specified.